# Backup users and roles WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i'm used wso2 api manager v2.2.0 for api gateway, and i've problem for backup users and roles, at the moment i'm used api-import-export-2.1.0, but just backup APIs, any advice for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Users and roles are in the user database, therefore you need to backup your user database (or any other userstore you use).

By default WSO2AM comes with H2 embedded database which is not really recommended (or suited) for production deployment and you should setup your own databases on any supported DB system.

If you still use the the embedded H2 database, by default the user database file is located at repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db , however I don't recommend to backup/copy the file while it is open (while wso2am is running).